# Why the return value does not release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I have some code like：

```
- (SendFileInfo *)sendFileInfoForName:(NSString *)name {
    for (SendFileInfo *sendFileInfo in sendArray)
    {
        if ([sendFileInfo.name isEqualToString:name])
        {
            return sendFileInfo;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So the return value of this method will be autorelease.I use instruments to track the retain/release event of SendFileInfo;Sometimes SendFileInfo will release after autorelease,just like:

```
Retain/Autorelease/Release (3) 00:48.146.622 ipjsua -[SendFileQueue sendFileInfoForName:]

Retain  +1  5   00:48.146.622   ipjsua  -[SendFileQueue sendFileInfoForName:]

Autorelease         00:48.146.627   ipjsua  -[SendMessageViewController refreshSendFileView:]

Release -1  4   00:48.155.558   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
```

But sometimes there is no release action, so the memory of this object will not be released.

```
Retain/Autorelease (2)  +1      00:46.996.752   ipjsua  -[SendFileQueue sendFileInfoForName:]

Retain  +1  2   00:46.996.752   ipjsua  -[SendFileQueue sendFileInfoForName:]

Autorelease         00:46.996.756   ipjsua  -[SendMessageViewController refreshSendFileView:]
```

In the end, the reference count of the SendFileInfo object is equal to the time the sendFileInfoForName method is called(which does not release after autorelease). Memory leak!
When does the release event happen? Why doesn't the release event happen in the same method?

Comment: The object you return is not subject to being additionally retained by that code, since it is known to be retained by the container object.  If you actually look at your trace info above you'll see that your second case is missing the release by GraphicsServices, which is external to the above code.

Comment: (I'm not familiar with GraphicsServices, but you are somehow enabling an event handler or some such with your problem object as the "data" value for it.  If that event handler is never triggered or cancelled your object remains retained.)

Answer (score 2):

An object will be released when there are no more references to it. The object you return, however is still strongly retained by the array `sendArray`. As soon as it leaves that collection, it will be released.

All types of collections, NSArrays, NSSets and NSDictionaries will strongly reference the object you add, meaning that they will "live" for the duration of the array's lifetime.

Comment: I know that.And I am very sure the object was already removed from the collection. This event ->(Release -1  4   00:48.155.558   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal), happened before object was removed from the collection.I can't figure out why this doesn't happen sometimes .And this leads to the memory leak.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is incorrect. An object will be deallocated (not released) when there are no more references to it.